# Non-default behavior when deleting rows from UITableView with cell has subview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, edit

I have a table view with a subview added to its cell:

```
[cell addSubview:[DrawingHelper cellView]];
```

I am enabling the edit behavior in the table view using:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

When I click the `Edit` Button, the minus red button appears but don't move the cell view content to the right as it should be...

**How can I restore the default behavior and at the same time keep adding a subview to the cellView?**

Comment: What about adding in cell's content view?.

Comment: Have you set the autoresizing mask of the subview? I believe that when showing the edit buttons, the table view will try to resize the content view but it need to have it's autoresizing mask set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can intercept the swipe on the cell and move the subview yourself before displaying the delete button in this **UITableViewDelegate** function:

```
tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:
```

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html